# Node.js POST: req.body empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Backend newbie here! I am trying to post from my frontEnd js to Node, but the body of the request always come in empty. I have read tons of answers here, but none helped me. this is my js trying to post:

```
const sendTest = () => {
  const data = createObject();
  if (data == false) {
    alert("fill everything!");
  } else {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    
    const parameters = {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      credentials: "same-origin",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3035/api/sendSoftSkills", parameters);
  }
};
```

JSON.stringfy(data):

```
{"ss1":"1","ss2":"1","ss3":"1","ss4":"2","ss5":"2","ss6":"2","ss7":"2","ss8":"2","ss9":"2","ss10":"2","ss11":"2","ss12":"1","ss13":"2","ss14":"1","ss15":"2","ss16":"1","ss17":"2","ss18":"1","ss19":"1","ss20":"1"}
```

on my node.js with express:

```
app.post("/api/sendSoftSkills", (req, res) => {
  console.log("POSTED!");
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

my terminal:

```
POSTED!
{}
```

I am using body-parser middleware. Am I missing something obvious?
Any help appreciated, thank!

Comment: Can you show us how you are using the body-parser middleware?

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the body:

```
app.use(express.json())
app.post("/api/sendSoftSkills", (req, res) => {
  console.log("POSTED!");
  console.log(req.body);
});
```